# laravel/admin encore in model form BelongsToMany relationship can not save file

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-admin

Hi everyone i have 3 tables: post (id), post_files (post_id, file_id) and files(file_name (file path), type(image/ video)) and i am using laravel/admin [encore](https://laravel-admin.org/docs/en/model-form-relationships#Many%20to%20many) to save file.

- In model Post i define:

```
    public function files()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(File::class, 'post_files', 'post_id', 'file_id');
    }
```

- In PostController i use:
  `$form->image('files.file_name', trans('post.post_media_file'))->required();`

when i save a post it said saving success and the post field are saving ok but the relationship tables (post, post_files) didn't save anything

Also when I check devtool network in the request sent i didn't saw file_name field but it is there i can add image and I'm sure the name file_name i already add too. [post_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weO13.png)

I have try to read docs and use some others relationship saving field but it did not work. So can i ask you guys how to detect the problem here and the solution to solve it ?